# Asterisk 13 unable to read the extensions.conf file

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, voip

I have an odd issue, asterisk was work just fine, then it suddenly stopped working.
when i make a call it always replay with code 404, which means user not found, which means it can't read the extensions.conf file, also when i do the command 
`dialplan reload` in asterisk cli, it replies with command not found, also when i do the command `core reload` in asterisk cli nothing happend.
i tried to restart the service and restart the server and still no solution.
please help me with this problem.

Comment: user not found is a `sip.conf` issue. Better you see `/var/log/asterisk` for details view of what happening.

Comment: users can register to asterisk, but they can't talk to each other.

Answer (score -1):

```
asterisk -r
core set verbose 10
dialplan reload
module reload
```

Comment: you may add some explanation. code-only answers are rarely useful.

Comment: Question is debug one, so it is offtopic and will be removed. What i pasted is enought to get more info, however if it not help, any other answer also will not help much,really.

Comment: the command dialplan reload doesn't exist, inspite off it was exist before.
when i do the command module reload the system just freez!!

Comment: That mean it not loaded YET. Check dns server working and your modules/configs.

Comment: @arheops 
could you be more specific

Comment: @arheops
could you be more specific.
which config?!
which module?!
i don't think it's a dns server problem, because users can register.
also if one or more module aren't loaded, why they don't reload when i restart the service and the server???

Comment: No idea which module is not okay. This one is debug task, which is offtopic on SO. Can recomend you read Orelly's "The future of telephony" book.

Answer (score -1):

It may be possible that your modules aren't loaded. Check if they exist. Sometimes file permissions of the modules can also create such problems. You can try rebuilding your asterisk too.